# How can I display mail image using html src tag for a page in Outlook ?

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, src

I am using a web page to log something, before displaying image in a mail. Html is;

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/abc.aspx?getlink=imagepath.jpg..."/>
```

Here is the code for page load on abc.aspx:

```
getLink = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["getlink"]);
byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(getLink);
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.End();
```

This image can display properly in hotmail,gmail etc. But images can not be displayed in outlook. Any idea?

Thanks..

Comment: have you allowed outlook to download external image sources?

Comment: Yes i do. when I allow image proxy authorization i can see the image in outlook. but my mails' images should display direct like the others that theirs src tag have direct jpg path.

Comment: right click at the base of your email window in Outlook and view the source - what is the image url?

Comment: when I do right click and copy image url and paste to browser, image display correctly.